# Problemas Framework Ionic

Tags: ionic

Bom estou com problema com o botão voltar, inicialmente pensei que o problema fosse no cordova, porem identifiquei que o problema na verdade é no ionic, procurando na internet achei o seguinte código:

```
  // Disable BACK button on home
  $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
    if($state.current.name=="app.home"){
      navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else {
      navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
  }, 100);
```

Porém está dando o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ionicPlatform is not defined

Estou colocando este código dentro de um novo documento chamado functionAngular.js e adiciono ele no final do `body`. Como devo informar esta função ?

Meu problema:

> Estou querendo que o botão voltar do `aparelho móvel` não saia da aplicação em outras telas a não ser a tela inicial. O problema que está dando que ao invés dele fazer isto, ele fecha a aplicação.

Agradeço desde já pelo auxilio.

Comment: Já tentou definir o `$ionicPlatform` ?

Comment: Definir aonde ?

Comment: Tentei registra da forma normal. Porem não fica visível o registerBaclButtonAction.

Comment: Exemplo: `.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução para meu problema foi ajustar o modulo do angular, além de inicializar a função, com o código final ficando como o código a seguir:

```
angular.module('ionic')

.run(function($ionicPlatform,$state,$ionicHistory){

 $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
    if($state.current.name=="app.home"){
      navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else {
       $ionicHistory.backHistory();
    }
  }, 100);

});
```

Comment: Definir o `$ionicPlatform` funcionou? Se sim, altere sua resposta e diga que foi isso que resolveu

Comment: Não, definir não funcionou, porque faltou adicionar o modulo.

Comment: Então ficaria melhor você editar a pergunta e colocar que alterou o modulo.